# Rodapé cobrindo outros widgets do Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando fazer um aplicativo bem simples, de listagem de filmes, mas quando fiz um rodapé, ele ficou por cima dos widgets do Scaffold, cobrindo alguns deles, desse jeito:

[image]

Segue o código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  bool mudado = false;
  final amountGet = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Isso é uma appBar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: amountGet,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Digite aqui sua busca',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          height: 230,
          width: 700,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "nome do filme",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "R\$ 55,00",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "VALOR TOTAL SELECIONADO: R\$ 65,40",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      return showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            content: Text(amountGet.text),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    color: Colors.indigo[800],
                    child: Text(
                      'Comprar',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  body() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                focusColor: Colors.grey,
                activeColor: Colors.grey[400],
                value: true,
                onChanged: (value) => value,
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Total:",
                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 20, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "R\$ 55,00",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Duração: 120 minutos",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Data Lançamento: 00/00/0000",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Direção: fulano",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer exibir uma lista, pelo que entendi, com a sua estrutura atual você pode utilizar o Widget `SingleChildScrollView`, para que você possa rolar entre os itens.

Como você vai trabalhar com uma *bottomSheet* fixa, uma saída é você redimencionr o seu body para caber dentro da tela.

Segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool mudado = false;
  final amountGet = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Isso é uma appBar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight - 230,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: amountGet,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Digite aqui sua busca',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),body(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: 
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          height: 230,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "nome do filme",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.grey[700],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "R\$ 55,00",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "VALOR TOTAL SELECIONADO: R\$ 65,40",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      return showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            content: Text(amountGet.text),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    color: Colors.indigo[800],
                    child: Text(
                      'Comprar',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  body() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                focusColor: Colors.grey,
                activeColor: Colors.grey[400],
                value: true,
                onChanged: (value) => value,
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Total:",
                    textScaleFactor: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 20, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      "R\$ 55,00",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Duração: 120 minutos",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Data Lançamento: 00/00/0000",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Direção: fulano",
                        textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Observação**

Você também pode fazer uso da `ListView`, que ao meu ver é o mais aconselhado para você, ao invés de utilizar um `SingleChildScrollView` junto com uma `Column`.

**Editado**

Você pode redimensionar a tua área de visualização, pegando o tamanho máximo da sua tela e subtraindo o tamanho do teu rodapé e também o tamanho da sua appbar

> height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight - 230

*kToolbarHeight: É uma constante do próprio SDK que retorna o tamanho padrão da appbar.*

Comment: Mesmo com o SingleChildScrollView(), o rodapé ainda está tampando a listinha.

Comment: @KayaRyuuna me desculpe, não percebia que o checkbox era o primeiro Widget de cada item... Você precisa realmente usar o _bottomSheet_?

Comment: Eu queria ter um rodapé nessa página, o bottomSheet foi uma das opções que eu encontrei, que deram certo, porém ele tampa os widgets. Ate tentei colocar junto do column, mas não deu certo.

Comment: @KayaRyuuna atualizei minha resposta

Comment: muito obrigado, eu nao conhecia essa função MediaQuery! Vai ser de grande ajuda no futuro! :D